# what does a red dot in VS code mean

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

So I'm learning vue.js and vsCode is giving me this red dot on my code, the code is running perfectly fine and other editors such as atom is giving me no errors. What is that red dot for?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a breakpoint (used for debugging). You can read about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_breakpoints).